# Minimize the ratio of a convex function and its derivative

Tags: calculus

Given function $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$. If $f(x)$ is convex in $(a,b)$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $a<x<b$.

Find $x$ within $(a,b)$ which minimize $$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$

Comment: See if you can justify that $x=a$ is the minimum (provided that $f'(a)\neq0$).

Comment: Do you want the interval to be closed? For instance take $f(x)=x^2$ on some positive open interval and this ratio has no minimum on that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Differentiate $f/f'$ and equate to zero, do you have any roots? Try given convexity and boundary conditions.